# How to save session id to my persistenceLogin table

Tags: spring, grails

Iam using spring-security-core-2.0 RC5 in my grails 2.4.4 application.
I created persistenceLogin domain using the command 's2-create-persistent-token'
I added an extra column session_id to the table. Now I need to save the session id to this column, how can i do this?
Do i need to customize the GormPersistentTokenRepository.groovy?
I'm not familiar with this plugin. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

In accrodance with [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html) you can retrieve session id this way:

```
session.id
```

Comment: But the GormPersistentTokenRepository.groovy is a plugin class, web request can not be accessed from here

Comment: @AbhilashShajan, and isn't there any chance to inherit from it or pass session id there somehow?

Comment: Yeah, I'm trying to do this, but i don't know from where this class been called since it is a plugin part. Meanwhile i need to get more familiarized with this plugin. I tried get the request from contextHolder also, but it is not working too.